# Show that $\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} e^{ik\theta}d\theta = 1$ or $0$ depending on $k$.

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

I'm asked the problem (restating from the question title),

$$\textrm{Show that }\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} e^{ik\theta}d\theta  = 
\begin{cases}
1,\, k=0\\
0, \, k\neq0
\end{cases}$$

---

**My Attempt:**

For the $k=0$ case, it's quite trivial to show that the integral would evaluate to $1$. However, for the case  where $k\neq0$, I'm a bit confused. I'll show you why.

Evaluating the integral directly,

$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} e^{ik\theta}d\theta & = \frac{1}{2\pi}\left(\frac{1}{ik}e^{ik\theta}\bigg|_0^{2\pi}\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi ik} (e^{2\pi ik}-1)
\end{align}
$$

The only way I can see that equaling to $0$ is if $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ due to the periodicity of the exponential term, but other than that I'm stumped.

Where did I go wrong? What's a better approach?

Comment: The thing you are asked to prove is only true if $k\in\mathbb Z$, I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've done all of the hard work already and it's all correct. Here's the way to see that you get $0$: $e^{ix} = \cos x + i\sin x$, so

$$e^{2\pi ik} = \cos 2\pi k + i\sin 2\pi k.$$

If $k$ is an integer, what do you know about $\cos 2\pi k$ and $\sin 2\pi k$?

Comment: But doesn't that rely on the assumption that $k\in\mathbb{Z}$? Am I supposed to assume that?

Comment: Yes you are. It is not true in general if $k\not\in \Bbb Z$.